# Regex replace uppercase with lowercase letters in PhpStorm/Webstorm (Intellij-IDEA)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Hey I have to change in a lot of places camelCase to snail_case.

I have following example:

```
billingAddress
paymentDetails
```

I tried to use find and replace with regex in PhpStorm

In 'find' input field I put in:

```
([A-Z])
```

In 'replace' input field I put in:

```
_\L$1
```

Result I got:

```
billing_LAddress
payment_LDetails
```

What do I need to change in order to get following result:

```
billing_address
payment_details
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First open Find and Replace functionality with **`CTRL`** + **`R`** and then check the boxes `Match Case` and `Regex` (and if necessary `In Selection`):

[image]

---

**1.** To replace *camelCase* to *snail_case* as in in the question:

*find:* `([A-Z])`
*replace:*  `_\l$1`

`someThing -> some_thing`

---

**2.** To replace *UPPERCASE* words to *lowercase* words use `\L`

*find:* `(\w*)`
*replace:* `\L$1`

`SOMETHING -> something`

---

**3.** To replace *lowercase* words to *UPPERCASE* words use `\U`

*find:* `(\w*)`
*replace:* `\U$1`

`something -> SOMETHING`

---

**4.** To replace first character of words with *lowercase* use `\l`

*find:* `(\w*)`
*replace:* `\l$1`

`Something -> something`

---

**5.** To replace first character of words with *UPPERCASE* use `\u`

*find:* `(\w*)`
*replace:* `\u$1`

`something -> Something`

---

## Note: Add some extra boundaries

You get best results by adding some additional boundaries that suit your specific case, for example single `'` or double quotes `"` or line breaks `\n`

---

## Regex Documentation

Check for details on additional Regular Expression Syntax the documentation for [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/regular-expressions.html) or [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/regular-expressions.html).

Answer (score 15):

According to the [PHPstorm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html) and according to my test, this works now:

```
_\l$1
```

Answer (score 3):

> What do I need to change in order to get following result:

Nothing/Everything. It's simply not supported ATM.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70451 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

**UPDATE:** 
This functionality is now implemented and available since PhpStorm v10.

Comment: This comment is outdated. Since Build 142.2822 it is possible as [documented here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html)